# Create a dataframe with two columns (hour and minute) using a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

Hi all I have a list with Datetime indexes in it, with time interval 15 minutes (see screenshot)

I would like to create a dataframe with 2 columns only, the first with 'hour' and the second with 'minute' using this Datetime index. [image]
The result I would like to be like this:

```
hour   minute

08     00

08     15
08     30 etc.
```

Is it possible?
thanks a lot!

Comment: In general, please post sample data as text, not image. That makes it much more easy to use in an exemplary solution. Then specifically to your problem, you can access individual attributes of a dti like `dti.hour` or `dti.minute`, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#sample data
L = [pd.Index([x]) for x in pd.date_range('2022-12-23 08:30', freq='15Min', periods=5)]
print (L)
[DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 08:30:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 08:45:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None),
 DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 09:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), 
 DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 09:15:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), 
 DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 09:30:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
```

Use list comprehension for tuples for minutes and hours with flattening:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(y.hour, y.minute) for x in L for y in x], columns=['hour','minute'])
print (df)
   hour  minute
0     8      30
1     8      45
2     9       0
3     9      15
4     9      30
```

Or:

```
idx = pd.Index([y for x in L for y in x])
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 08:30:00', '2022-12-23 08:45:00',
               '2022-12-23 09:00:00', '2022-12-23 09:15:00',
               '2022-12-23 09:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':idx.hour, 'minute':idx.minute})
print (df)
   hour  minute
0     8      30
1     8      45
2     9       0
3     9      15
4     9      30
```

If always one element index values is possible select first value by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(x[0].hour, x[0].minute) for x in L], columns=['hour','minute'])
print (df)
   hour  minute
0     8      30
1     8      45
2     9       0
3     9      15
4     9      30
```

Or:

```
idx = pd.Index([x[0] for x in L])
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-23 08:30:00', '2022-12-23 08:45:00',
               '2022-12-23 09:00:00', '2022-12-23 09:15:00',
               '2022-12-23 09:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':idx.hour, 'minute':idx.minute})
print (df)
   hour  minute
0     8      30
1     8      45
2     9       0
3     9      15
4     9      30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your column you can create them using:

```
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['minute'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.minute)
```

Or without lambda:

```
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['timestamp'].dt.minute
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i*900) for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['timestamp'])
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['minute'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.minute)
```

result:

```
                   timestamp  hour  minute
0 2023-01-11 12:08:31.045411    12       8
1 2023-01-11 12:23:31.045411    12      23
2 2023-01-11 12:38:31.045411    12      38
3 2023-01-11 12:53:31.045411    12      53
4 2023-01-11 13:08:31.045411    13       8
5 2023-01-11 13:23:31.045411    13      23
6 2023-01-11 13:38:31.045411    13      38
7 2023-01-11 13:53:31.045411    13      53
8 2023-01-11 14:08:31.045411    14       8
9 2023-01-11 14:23:31.045411    14      23
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, I used the above one and it works fine!!